# AcquireTokenFailure `AADSTS700051`

Tags: azure-active-directory

I just setup a `Azure Active Directory` tenant and I have an application using oAuth2 `Implicit` Flow.  I get the following error

`"_error":"AADSTS700051: response_type 'token' is not enabled for the application.`

Is there a configuration setting in the Azure AD dashboard tenant that resolves this error?

Comment: Does your app manifest have `oauth2AllowImplicitFlow` set as true? that's an important setting needed when you're trying to use Implicit grant flow.. if it's `false` then try changing it to `true`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 'token' is not enabled for the application

I have ever got this error, you could follow how Rohit said to fix this. You could modify the app manifest or select token in the **Authentication** (only for app registered in App registration(preview).

- **In the app manifest:**

[image]

- **In the App registration (preview):**

[image]