# Outlook app registration - response type token not enabled

Tags: rest, outlook, azure-active-directory

I've created an Azure app to contact an Outlook account to retrieve contact information from the users account. I have followed the instructions on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/javascript-tutorial but I am hitting a problem with the below error message:

> AADSTS700051: response_type 'token' is not enabled for the
>   application.

Can't see where the issue is, I've even deleted the app and created it again, but hitting the same problem.

The app has Implicit Grant > ID token enabled.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AcquireTokenFailure \`AADSTS700051\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55622603/acquiretokenfailure-aadsts700051)

Answer (score 0):

A value of `token` in the `response_type` of an an authorization request means the application is requesting an *access* token in the response as part of the Implicit Grant flow.

To allow an application to obtain access tokens using the Implicit Grant flow, in the Azure portal, check "Access tokens" under App registrations > (select the app) > Authentication > Implicit grant:

[image: Enable access tokens with Implicit Grant flow]

Comment: Great thank you, that worked so all good. Managed to pull back email, contacts and calender objects.

I am now trying to take out the limit to source size, so using client.api("/me/contacts/").top(10)... I now want to get all contacts (i.e. without the .top(X) element) but when I remove this it errors so assuming it is needed. How would you get this, e.g. .top(all)?

Comment: It's best to ask a new question if you have additional questions (after searching for an existing answer).